# How to conduct such lines in Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

[image]

That is not just a box. Namely, with an increase towards the center.
Or maybe it is best to SVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Forms ListView has the property [SeparatorVisibility](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.SeparatorVisibility/) were you can show and hide a separator. But its a straight line.

To achieve your needs you can:

1. Create a [custom cell](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/viewcell/) and add that separator has an image resource (/svg).
2. Extend ListView [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/listview/) and personalize the separator natively.